# problem to show labels using enumerate package with polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia

with this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\begin{english}
\begin{enumerate}[{example}- a)]
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

compiled with `XeLaTeX` labels 'a','b',... Does not appear in the output 
[image]

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the default language is Arabic, `polyglossia` redefines `\@alph` to use Arabic letters, but apparently it does not restore the definition when `english` is used.

There should be a better way to do this, but until there isn't, use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\appto\blockextras@english{%
  \let\@savealph\@alph
  \let\@alph\@origalph
}
\appto\noextras@english{\let\@alph@savealph}
\makeatother

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\begin{english}
\begin{enumerate}[label=example-\alph*)]
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Also `enumerate` would work, but `enumitem` is more powerful.

[image]

Comment: The same thing with \Alph,\arabic , thanks.