# polyglossia and Latin enumerate problem

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, polyglossia, arabic

I use `polyglossia` package and when I try to enumerate in this way ( 6a,6b,6c,,, ) it changes to arabic alphabet. how can I write it in the way I want it (6a,6b,6c).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{$#1 _ #2$}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={6}\Alph*]
\item خوایه‌ وه‌ته‌ن    
\item  چه‌ند دڵگیر و شیرینه‌
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Remark:- I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194424/problem-to-show-labels-using-enumerate-package-with-polyglossia) to my question, but now if I write kurdish language after 
`\item` it will not shown, only Latin text will be appear which is again a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recover  the definition of `\@alph` you can add

```
\appto\arabic@numbers{%
   \let\@alph\@origalph%
   \let\@Alph\@origAlph%
   }
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{$#1 _ #2$}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}

\makeatletter
\appto\arabic@numbers{%
   \let\@alph\@origalph%
   \let\@Alph\@origAlph%
   }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={6}\alph*]
\item خوایه‌ وه‌ته‌ن    
\item  چه‌ند دڵگیر و شیرینه‌
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```